# What is wrong with the syntax of this python code?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

```
 File "<ipython-input-4-fa24f1a53d20>", line 6
    return x**3 – 2*x**2 + 1
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here as well? So that we can check it

Comment: Please _always_ include a language tag. There are many programming languages, each with their own syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried retyping the minus sign?